# Differentiability of a composition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f: \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^3, f(x) = (x_1,x_1x_2, x_2)$ , $g : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R, g(x) = \|x\|^2$ and let $h:= gf:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3.$ Show that $h$ is differentiable and find $Dh(x_0)$ at $x_0=(1,-1).$

So we need to find the Jacobian of the composition $gf$ and then see if the partials are continuous to determine if it's differentiable and afterwards evaluate it at $(1,-1)$? This feels a bit weird since if I can find the Jacobian isn't the function already differentiable?

Also finding the composition $h$ feels  a bit weird... I have that $h=g(f(x)) = x_1^2+(x_1x_2)^2$?

Comment: To prove that $h$ is differentiable at $x_0$, you need to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and that $g$ is differentiable at $f(x_0)$

Comment: Is it enough to find the partials of $f$ and $g$ and see if they're continuous?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember these theorems anymore, so the way I'd do it is just using the definition of differentiability (limit)

Comment: @Daniel If the partial derivatives are continuous in a neighbourhood of a given point, the function is differentiable.

Comment: My idea was to find $h$ and then compute the partials and based on their continuity I could determine that $h$ is differentiable. However the composition seems weird it maps from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$, how can it output a 3-dimensional vector function?

Comment: @Daniel Please check the exercise... $g \circ f$ is not well defined because $f$ returns a vector of dimension $3$ and $g$ takes in a vector of dimension 2. You must have $g:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see that seemed a bit fishy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is very simple to compute $g \circ f$:

$$(g \circ f)(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2 + (x_1 x_2)^2 + x_2^2.$$

Since this is a polynomial function, it will be continuous everywhere, as well as its partial derivatives. Is is therefore differentiable everywhere and, in particular, at (1,-1).